# How should understand this "int operator-(int value)" and the output in this program?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

(Visual Studio 2012)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Bar
{
public:
    int operator-(int value)
    {
        return 5;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bar bar;
    cout<<"First: "<<bar-10<<endl;
    cin.ignore(100,'\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Two questions:

1. In class, there is an overloaded for `-` sign,  as long as the right value is an integer, it will return `5`, am I right?
2. In the output part `cout<<"Second: "<<bar-10<<endl;`, if there is not an object before `-10`, it will output `-10`; if an object is put there, it will outputs `5`, why?  And what role does the object `bar` play?

Comment: Did your test question 1? And question 2 doesn't appear to be a question.

Comment: Please click [edit] and complete the second question. Also complete the code to *include* `cout << "Second:"` part.

Comment: @Biffen Rofl. Twice now you've posted the same thing as me like 10 seconds before.

Comment: @Biffen In the other question, you posted with in-built links. Do you have premades or do you write it from scratch?

Comment: @Biffen Cool, thanks.

Comment: @PeterZhang Sounds like you should read about operator overloading. Trying to answer this question would just result in huge description of how it works, and such descriptions can already be found in books as well as online.

Comment: If there's no object on the left of the operator, then it's clearly the unary `-` that's used for negating a number. If there is a `Bar` object, it's the binary `-` operator defined in `Bar`. In either of these cases, there is only one way to interpret the expression, as far as I can see.

Comment: @BoPersson You have taken quite a shot in the dark with that edit.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, thanks for replying, I have tested it several times, it always outputs 5. Question 2,  it may not be a typical question, sorry for that. The key point was that what kind of role does  the object "bar" play here? Thanks again.

Comment: @FabioTurati Not if you look at the source. It was simple a matter of some unescaped ‘HTML’.

Comment: @Biffen You are right, I had checked "Side by side" but not "Side by side Markdown". I thought Bo had completed the question with words coming from nowhere, and I was surprised, but everything is clear now. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterZhang Of course your method always returns 5. What do you think `return 5;` means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. In class, there is an overloaded for "-" sign, as long as ther rightvalue is an integer, it will return 5, am I right?

Yes. Operator `-` is overloaded in such a way that subtracting any integer from `Bar` produces a fixed value of `5`.

> 2. In the output part `cout<<"Second: "<<bar-10<<endl;` if there is not an object before `-10`, it will output `-10`; if an object is put there, it will outputs `5`. Why? What role does the object `bar` play?

If you remove `bar`, dash becomes a unary minus operator in front of ten, turning it into negative ten. That is what gets printed.

When `bar` is there, dash is interpreted as a binary subtraction operation, with `bar` its left-hand side operand, and `10` its right-hand side operator. Since `Bar` class provides an override, this is what C++ calls to produce `5` as the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @dasblinkenlight, it is now clear to me. Your answer is a huge encouragement for a beginner. Wish you have a good 2017 .